# ListViewWebpart SubFolder

Tags: sharepoint

I created a custom user control using Visual Studio 2010 and programmatically added a listview web part. In my SharePoint 2010 site, I created a document library and a folder inside the library.

Using the following code:

```cs
FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName,System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

I am able to set the sub-folder as root folder for the list view web part. Till this point everything works fine. But when I try to upload a file, the list view web part uploads the file to the library’s root folder and not to the sub-folder.

Any pointers on how to make the list view web part to upload files to the sub-folder is very much appreciated.